# setOnClickListener complains that I should use setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have the following code which worked before. Then after I started working on another activity (implementing ListActivity and providing a custom view per row by extending an ArrayAdapter), I start getting the RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ezport/com.ezport.EzportActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

Here is the code

```
package com.ezport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    
public class EzportActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View view_orders_button = findViewById(R.id.view_orders_button);
        view_orders_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        View submit_invoice_button = findViewById(R.id.submit_invoice_button);
        submit_invoice_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        View help_button = findViewById(R.id.help_button);
        help_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.view_orders_button:
            Intent order_intent = new Intent(this, OrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(order_intent);
            break;
        case R.id.submit_invoice_button:
            //Intent i = new Intent(this, )
            break;
        case R.id.help_button:
            Intent help_intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(help_intent);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: have you added `ListView` to this activity ?

Comment: any luck on this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This works for me and it might fix your problem, it looks like good code i wouldn't see why else it wouldnt be working.

Comment: I tried that and it does work. But it also could have been another part of the code. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, but the code was compiling and working fine before.

What actually happened was, that I had reordered items in the XML layout file. After (Eclicpe) Menu - Project - Clean I was fine again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to specific View. Say if you are using ImageButton then instead of this

```
View help_button = findViewById(R.id.help_button);
```

Use this

```
ImageButton help_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.help_button);
```